How do I smooth out the curve in my render?
I'm using Blender 2.93. The curve of my object looks like a curve when viewed from the top (image on right), but the edge in my cycles or eevee preview of camera shot (image on left) looks like the curve as been reduced into line segments. How can I get the curve to render out as a curve? Is there some setting I need to turn on? Thanks.


You want to increase the Resolution Preview U property (under Shape), or the Render U property. Per the 2.93 docs, if you set Render U to 0, then the renderer will use whatever setting is used for the preview; alternatively, you can set it higher for even smoother appearance during rendering.
How is the geometry generated from your curve?

Hi, thanks for the info but where is this Resolution Preview U physically located in the Blender UI? The objects were sketched with lines and arcs in SolidWorks and the shape extruded to 1/8" thickness. I then exported it as a .PLY from SolidWorks to bring into Blender. Thanks for the help.
